# Trouble updating a UIImageView selected from iphone photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm using the code below to retrieve an image from the iphone photo library. `self.selectedImageView.image` is an image view located on top of the view of the current view controller. Everything in xcode seems linked correctly; the image view is wired and so fourth.

**Problem:**
After selecting an image I can see that this method is called but the new image does not update. The image view is completely blank.

**Question:** Is their some sort of refreshing that needs to take place after reassigning a new image to an image view?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"image selected");
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.selectedImageView.image = chosenImage;        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` instead. The key your currently using, `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`, is for accessing images that the user has edited.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

 // Get the image first then dismiss the controller. 
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 self.selectedImageView.image = chosenImage;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added a comment explaining what was different about this code, basically the use of the different key for accessing the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

may this help you and above posted code by Gyanendra singh also correct even you can follow his code also.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  //here we are storing the image in uiimage after selecting from library
   UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //set image to image view
    [imageView setImage:image];
    //after selecting photo from library dismiss photo library
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```